# SuiteCRM Detail View and Create View is not displaying anything

Tags: suitecrm

I’m not getting any detail view and create view for pdf-templates modules is displaying blank. I was receiving this error message at first when I request create view it showing error i.e. “There was an error processing your request, please try again at a later time. But I’m no longer receiving the error message, after disable ajax and re-enable; however, the create and edit page is completely blank now. I have done a quick rebuild and repair. I’m not seeing any error in the php error logs.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means a missing PHP package or incorrect folder permissions.

Make sure you set `debug` as the level for suitecrm logging in the Administration -> Settings.

One trick I use to check if the system contains all the required PHP -packages is to try to install a new instance in a new folder, the Installer has a system validation that you can use to verify if everything is setup correctly.